# how to enable filter for Image in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, imagefilter

I have an Image View that contains image and I want to add filter to the image I used codes for filter and then put new image instead of old image here is my code:

```
let filterNames = CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: nil)

@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!

@IBAction func filter1(_ sender: Any) {

    func simpleBlurFilterExample(myImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        // convert UIImage to CIImage
        let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: myImage)!

        // Create Blur CIFilter, and set the input image
        let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
        blurFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter.setValue(8, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

        // Get the filtered output image and return it
        let myImage = blurFilter.outputImage!
        return UIImage(ciImage: myImage)


    }



}
```

as you see here i have an outlet image that named my image and I want input image to be my image and after pushing button change image to the output image with filter

Comment: So where is the issue. IS this code not working? What is the error?

Comment: Not Working at all without error

Comment: are you setting the image returned form this function to your imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the image in the UIImageView

```
myImage.image = filter1(myImage: myImage.image)
```

Maybe you should call the imageView myImageView to reduce confusion as well

Comment: This will work but when user wants to use the filter again the app will crash

Comment: how will the app crash?

Comment: Its ok before your code I used         myImage.image = UIImage(named: "2.jpg") to do the filter again thanks a lot please vote my question

Answer (score 0):

You can set initial image for your UIImageView with Storyboard or programmatically, maybe viewDidLoad `myImage.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")`. Then call `simpleBlurFilterExample` function with parameter `myImage.image` and use return value.

```
        @IBAction func filter1(_ sender: Any) {
               myImage.image = simpleBlurFilterExample(myImage: myImage.image)
        }

        func simpleBlurFilterExample(myImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
                // convert UIImage to CIImage
                let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: myImage)!

                // Create Blur CIFilter, and set the input image
                let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
                blurFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                blurFilter.setValue(8, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

                // Get the filtered output image and return it
                let myImage = blurFilter.outputImage!
                return UIImage(ciImage: myImage)
}
```

Comment: its working but I will get Error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code and use right methods of CIimage with correct optionals

```
@IBAction func filter1(_ sender: Any) {
           myImage.image = simpleBlurFilterExample(myImage: myImage.image)
    }

    func simpleBlurFilterExample(myImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
            // convert UIImage to CIImage
            let inputCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: myImage.cgImage!)

            // Create Blur CIFilter, and set the input image
            let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
            blurFilter?.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            blurFilter?.setValue(8, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

            if let output = blurFilter?.outputImage {

              return UIImage(ciImage: output)

            }else{
              return myImage
            }

}
```

Comment: the app will crash because of this line             return UIImage(cgImage: output  as! CGImage )

Comment: thread 1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode = 0x0)

Comment: edited it. Check now and should work. I tried with my setup and it worked. It was a mistake of using CIimage as CGimage.

Comment: thanks It will work But Take lots of seconds to do the effect how can it work faster?

Comment: I just bring image view in story board and bring a button to add effect on it

Comment: Then it should hardly take 1-2 seconds. How much time is it taking for you?

Comment: about 4 seconds or even more ! But I saw in instagram the filter will done just after user tap button!

Comment: Can you print time before and after the method call to see what is the time printer. Are you using the same code as in my answer or any other. I tried with my answer and it took less than 100 milliseconds